# Extract method from jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring

I'm trying to extrac a method from this function:

```
addWidgetControls: function () {
        var iNettuts = this,
            $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings;

        $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
            var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(this.id);
            if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
                $('<a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }).click(function () {
                    $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                        opacity: 0
                    }, function () {
                        $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                            $(this).remove();
                        });
                    });

                    return false;
                }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));
            }

            if (thisWidgetSettings.collapsible) {
                $('<a href="#" class="collapse">COLLAPSE</a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }).toggle(function () {
                    $(this).css({ backgroundPosition: '-38px 0' })
                        .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                            .find(settings.contentSelector).hide();
                    return false;
                }, function () {
                    $(this).css({ backgroundPosition: '' })
                        .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                            .find(settings.contentSelector).show();
                    return false;
                }).prependTo($(settings.handleSelector, this));
            }
        });
    },
```

I've extracted the code from this function like this:

```
addWidgetControls: function () {
        var iNettuts = this,
            $ = this.jQuery,
            settings = this.settings,
            func = this.doWidget;

        $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () {
            func(this);
        });
    },

    doWidget: function (widg) {
        $ = jQuery;
        settings = iNettuts.settings;
        var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(widg.id);
        if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) {
            $('<a href="#" class="remove"></a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }).click(function () {
                $(widg).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, function () {
                    widg.wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () {
                        widg.remove();
                    });
                });

                return false;
            }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, widg));
        }

        if (thisWidgetSettings.collapsible) {
            $('<a href="#" class="collapse"></a>').mousedown(function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
            }).toggle(function () {
                $(widg).css({ backgroundPosition: '-38px 0' })
                        .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                            .find(settings.contentSelector).hide();
                return false;
            }, function () {
                $(widg).css({ backgroundPosition: '' })
                        .parents(settings.widgetSelector)
                            .find(settings.contentSelector).show();
                return false;
            }).prependTo($(settings.handleSelector, widg));
        }
    },
```

I've just copied the function code, replaced `this` with `widg` and added `widg` as an argument. Maybe there is a difference between `$(widge)` and `widg`.
But it doesn't work. What am I missing? Is there a tool that can do this easily? Thanks.

PS: By the way, this is grabbed from [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved and it was really interesting and easy to find! The this pointer, as we all know, is different from time to time, and in this case, there were only 3 instances of this that should've been replaced with widg. So here is the final code:

```
addWidgetControls: function () { 
    var iNettuts = this, 
        $ = this.jQuery, 
        settings = this.settings, 
        func = this.doWidget; 

    $(settings.widgetSelector, $(settings.columns)).each(function () { 
        func(this); 
    }); 
}, 

doWidget: function (wid) { 
    var $ = iNettuts.jQuery, 
        settings = iNettuts.settings; 

    var thisWidgetSettings = iNettuts.getWidgetSettings(wid.id); 
    if (thisWidgetSettings.removable) { 
        $('<a href="#" class="remove"></a>').mousedown(function (e) { 
            e.stopPropagation(); 
        }).click(function () { 
            $(this).parents(settings.widgetSelector).animate({ 
                opacity: 0 
            }, function () { 
                $(this).wrap('<div/>').parent().slideUp(function () { 
                    $(this).remove(); 
                }); 
            }); 

            return false; 
        }).appendTo($(settings.handleSelector, wid)); 
    } 

    if (thisWidgetSettings.collapsible) { 
        $('<a href="#" class="collapse"></a>').mousedown(function (e) { 
            e.stopPropagation(); 
        }).toggle(function () { 
            $(this).css({ backgroundPosition: '-38px 0' }) 
                    .parents(settings.widgetSelector) 
                        .find(settings.contentSelector).hide(); 
            return false; 
        }, function () { 
            $(this).css({ backgroundPosition: '' }) 
                    .parents(settings.widgetSelector) 
                        .find(settings.contentSelector).show(); 
            return false; 
        }).prependTo($(settings.handleSelector, wid)); 
    } 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you want to split `addWidgetControls` and `doWidget`

In your implementation, you dont have access to local variables declared in `addWidgetControls`, namely `iNettuts` (`$` and `settings` either, but you can access them from the upper level.

`var iNettuts = this,` is your problem. the best way in your situation is, i guess, to declare `iNettuts` out of the scope of `addWidgetControls`, so it's accessible by `doWidget` too. if it's the full object, you can redeclare `iNettuts` locally in `doWidget` exactly like in `addWidgetControls`.

On a side note, you don't need to declare redeclare doWiget as `func` in `addWidgetControls`, just call it directly like this: `iNettuts.doWidget(this);`

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is the problem since iNettuts is a global object and I've added two variables to fix the problem you're referring to (`$ = jQuery; settings = iNettuts.settings;`). To explain the problem more, I have to say that the changes in the code are added (the close and collapse buttons are added to the gadget) but when I click on them, nothing will happen. Maybe this will help finding the problem.